# Invoices - capture online vs capture offline

Tags: orders, invoice

Regarding invoices, can anyone explain the difference between the *online amount capture* and *offline amount capture*.

I really don't understand the difference between these two options.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Capture Offline will simple generate the invoice and mark the order as processing, which means the amount has been received manually. works for money orders kind of payment methods.

Capture online will connect with the gateways to capture the amount. like when you charge credit cards using any gateway.

Comment: ok in my case mine, invoices are created before payment.My customers pay after receiving the order.So I have to use capture offline?

Comment: well if invoices are already created and order is marked as processing, then you won't be able to create another invoice.

Comment: if your payment method auto generates the invoices, but you receive money after order placement, you should disable the auto invoicing, and once you receive money you can generate the invoice manually, and select Capture offline.

Comment: My method of payment does not automatically generate invoices so no matter if I chose capture online or offline?

Comment: if you receive money manually, and the payment method is not connected with any gateway like money order, then you can use any option.

Comment: ok thank you for your help.is that you know a plugin that allows to boost customer by letter if the status is still pending

Comment: sorry i don't know any, but you may find on web otherwise hire a developer to make one. :)

Comment: What is Not Capture option ?